# Swiss German: origin of gsi (gewesen)

Tags: etymology, dialect, swiss-standard-german, swiss-german

Swiss German speakers use **gsi** in place of **[gewesen](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gewesen)**.

What is the origin of **gsi**?

Was there ever a old form **gesein** that sounds like **gsi** in the dialect? (my amateur opinion)

Comment: With my dialect (SG/GR), I rather pronounce it like "*gse*".

Comment: Interesting.....

Comment: I confused things. Meant to address Graubünden. Edited now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Die Bildung des Partizips *gewesen* aus *sein* wurde [nach Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS25450#XGS25450) bereits sehr früh im Gotischen vollzogen.

Erst viel später trat eine weitere Form **gesîn** in Anlehnung von **sîn** auf, die sich in mehreren mittelhochdeutschen Dialekten findet:

> **gesîn** ist besonders dem alem. eigen und hier seit dem 12. jahrh. die gewöhnlichste form.

Das heißt, dass in den alemannischen Dialekten, zu dem auch die Schweizer Mundart gehört, diese Form seit dem 12. Jahrhundert vorherrscht.

Das heutige **gsî** ist demnach eine Kontraktur der älteren Form **gesîn**.

Answer (score 2):

In dialects "gewesen" can have various shortened forms.

gewesen g.we..n (The dot stands for dropped sounds.)

gewesen to g...sen to gse to gsi ( my assumption)

My grandfather even used the form gewest (regular) in a poem (Frankish).

During World War I, with a bullet in his arm and taken prisoner by the French near Metz, he wrote a letter in verse to his wife. He told her:

Mich trugen Krankenträger fort,

Und zwar in den nächsten Ort,

Rutzi hieß das elende Nest,

Wo wir sind fünf Tag' gewest.

Comment: I remember hearing that swiss german is based on old high german, which would explain it since "gesein" is old german, and in swiss german "ei" is pronounced "ie" (eg. "Schweiz -> "Schwiiz"). Like most dialects, they drop off the last "n" in verbs, so "gesein" became "gesie" (pronounced "gsi").